# See full compiler error when an error is truncated in lsp-mode?

Tags: lsp-mode, lsp-ui

Sometimes lsp-ui (I think it's `lsp-ui-sideline` specifically) will truncate messages so they fit on one line -- in this case a TypeScript compiler error:

[image]

Note the full error message ends with `is not assignable to parameter of type 'Stringable'.`, but what's shown omits the last part of that:  `'Stringable'.`.

Is there a way to see the full error in emacs when this happens?  What I'm hoping for is a command or possibly log file that will show the full error, not for the full error to be displayed in the sideline by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lsp-mode` uses `flycheck`, so `M-x flycheck-copy-errors-as-kill` (`SPC e y` in spacemacs) will both display the full text of the errors at point in the minibuffer, and copy the text to the kill ring, from where you can paste it where you like.